# Values from file don't expand as x axis in D3.js using x.domain?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following .tsv file format:

```
date    Edward Snowden    Urban Gardening    Barack Obama

2014-W15    14  3   34

2014-W16    3   5   54

2014-W17    5   15  34
```

I want the date displayed on the x axis with the minimum and maximum value extracted from the file and the other values as three lines on the y axis.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-W%U").parse;
d3.tsv("test.tsv", function(data) {
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
          });

          //set min max values of axis
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
});
```

I just extracted that piece of code, not sure if it can be used as minimal example. However, the problem is that there is no x axis expanding according to the values from the file. With other files where `date` was formatted as `%Y%m%d` it was working.

Comment: Hey, how the date object is created just by week number and year. Kindly pass the date(day), month and year. Even hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds are optional, because when we use Year,Month and Day to create date this date object time will be 00:00:00. Pass the proper values.

Comment: Oh, isn't it possible, as you stated with time being 0 if not specified further, to have the same for day being 0 if I don't specify? S.t. only weeks are displayed as ticks on the x axis? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your formatting is like saikiran says: The only correct value is the year. Your min and max value are the same, because every date passed within the same year is parsed to:

**Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)**

I know this because i have executed following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>barcode chart</title>   
    <style>
        body {height:100vh !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart">
    </div>



    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
    <script>

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-W%U").parse;
    var date1 = parseDate("2014-W16");
    var date2 = parseDate("2015-W25");
    var date3 = parseDate("2014-W36");

    console.log(date1);
    console.log(date2);
    console.log(date3);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The results in the browser were as following:

```
Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
```

And the only reason that there is a Thu jan 01 2015 is because there is value with year 2015 as input.

So I guess you will need to find a way to get the real date or you can also try to use ordinal scales. Also, beware that you don't mix the terms axis and scales. Output values with a domain and a range are calculated with scales. The axis which shows values (as ticks) uses a scale for its ticks. I say this, because in your code I see the following:

```
//set min max values of axis
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

But x cannot be an axis function, because d3.svg.axis() does not have a domain function. Just saying though ;-).

More information on ordinal scales can be found [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales)

**EDIT**

Here is how I would implement the ordinal scale:

```
d3.tsv("test.tsv", function(data) {

          var xDomainValues = []; //you need an array for your domain

          data.forEach(function(d) {
             xDomainValues.push(d.date); //d.date is a string value here, but that is ok
          });

          //this ordinal scale will calculate a value between 0 and graphWidth 
          //for each value in the xDomainValues array
          var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                               .domain(xDomainValues)
                               .rangeRoundPoints([0, graphWidth]); 

          var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(xScale)
                            .orient("bottom"); //I oriented the tick texts on the bottom.
});
```

The xAxis should now expand nicely as you intended. I would seriously consider using ordinal scales in your case, but do mind: I am not a D3 expert, I am just familiar with the basics.

Comment: Ok, so would it make sense to use an ordinal scale with the same domain and range, since I have the time formatted as specified in my file and want it output exactly like that?

Comment: I adjusted my answer. To me it would make sense to use an ordinal scale.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. One more question: say I wanted to display only every second tick, i.e. half the xDomainValues. Is it possible to keep the datapoints and only adjust the domain?

Comment: My pleasure. As far as I know, it is possible to influence the amount of ticks. You would do that on your axis, not by the domain of your scale function. I must say however, i strongly advice you to look into the axes documentation, as I am not experienced in influencing ticks :-). The axes documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes)